# np.genfromtxt is not working for csv file column

Tags: python

I have a csv file in this format 
[image]

I want to get all the NSN column values into an array. so I used this code

```
import numpy as np

csv = np.genfromtxt ('RFQ8s.csv', delimiter=",")
getNSN = csv[:,1]
print(getNSN)
```

but this is the ouput of the code 
[image]
what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
csv = np.genfromtxt ('RFQ8s.csv',  dtype='str', delimiter=",", skip_header=1)
```

If you want `NSN`, it is `csv[:, 0]`

You can find more details about the options from [this document page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html).